# Office365 list contacts using EWS returns The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

I have build a C# application using Exchange Web Services to read Outlook Contact data from Office 365. Until April 2013, this was working just fine. However, Office 365 has been updated. Now, when I query contact data I receive an Exception "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
I read some info about SharePoint Online App authentication, but can't find any details on MSDN. Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Did you go through http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/office_365_service_updates/default.aspx to check what changed? Maybe showing some code helps too.

Comment: Hello Jan, I didn't. I received a tip about Autodiscover, which was the key to my solution. http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/p/23447/486425.aspx#486425

Comment: Good that you found it. Please write an answer here (not just a link) to your own question, so that others can benefit. You can mark it as the correct answer after 48 hours.